# Compare dictionary both key and values and out put unmatched values to a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to compare 2 dictionaries as below:

```
dic1 = {
    'a': ['a1', 'a2'],
    'b': ['b1', 'b2'],
    'c': ['c1', 'c2']
}
dic2 = {
    'a': ['a1', 'a3'],
    'b': ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4']
}
```

The output should show only items that in dic2 but not in dic1 and look like below:

```
output = {
    'a': 'a3',
    'b': ['b3','b4']
}

nomatch = {
    'c': ['c1','c2']
}
```

I am new to Python so I have been struggle to make it work.

```
key_d1 = dic1.keys()
key_d2 = dic2.keys()
value_d1 = dic1.values()
value_d2 = dic2.values()

output = {}
nomatch = {}

for i, j in zip(key_d1, value_d1):
    if i in key_d2:
        if j not in value_d2:
            output = ??
    else:
        nomatch[i] = j
```

Comment: "show only items that in dic2 but not in dic1" The example output you provided doesn't match that description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this simply with a dictionary comprehension.

```
dict1 = {
    'a': ['a1', 'a2'],
    'b': ['b1', 'b2'],
    'c': ['c1', 'c2']
}
dict2 = {
    'a': ['a1', 'a3'],
    'b': ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'],
    'd': ['d1', 'd2']
}

d = { key : [element for element in elements if element not in dict1.get(key, [])] 
    for key, elements in dict2.items()
}
print(d)
```

However, I suspect you made a mistake in the question.

> show only items that in `dict2` but not in `dict1`

That would look like this:

```
{
    'a': ['a3'],
    'b': ['b3', 'b4'],
    'd': ['d1', 'd2']
}
```

Which is not the example output you provided.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I did make a mistake in my question and just updated it again. The output i only want to show the values that in d2 but not in d1 e.g output = {'a':'a3', 'b':['b3','b4']}.

Comment: the code generate an error if an item is in dict2 but not in dict1: e.g: item 'd':'d1' in in dict2 but not dict1. Any suggestion to solve this issue?

Comment: @Tim I'll have to check it out later. Ping me again in a few hours

Comment: Thanks Alex. I tried to modify your code: d={k: [e for e in v if e not in dict1[k]] for k, v in zip(dict1.viewkeys()&dict2.viewkeys(),dict2.values()}  .It does not show error and work for the sample above. However in my real data set, it starts comparing values of different keys thus created false result.

Comment: @Tim I updated my answer. Just use `get` instead of indexing the dictionary, and provide an empty list `[]` as the default value

Comment: yeah, i knew why my modification didnt work now. I managed to get it works using for loop however your code is much shorter and just elegant!!! Really appreciated for your help!